# Not able to plot numpy dataset using seaborn.kdeplot()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I am using seaborn to plot my dataset.
**(i) Here is my first part of the code which shows the plot in the link below the code:**

```
data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0],[[5,2],[2,2]],size=2000)
data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x','y'])
for col in 'xy':
    plt.hist(data[col],density=True,alpha=0.5)
```

[Image of Histogram of the above data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaZjZ.png)

**(ii)Second part of the code is here:**

```
sns.kdeplot(data)
```

I am getting this error while running the second part:

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: Try `sns.kdeplot(data=data, x='x', y='y')`. Or leave out the conversion to a dataframe?

Comment: @JohanC This works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the second part of the code**

Make this change:

```
sns.kdeplot(data=data,x='x',y='y')
```